# response json web services with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0

Hi i have my web services with Jersey and i use jackson for the generating JSON object i have for example my resource TESTS with set/get method:

```
public class Tests {

    private String name;

    private String result;

    private String credit;

}
```

my api:

```
@Path("/getTests")
    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void listsTests(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response) {

       ListenableFuture<Collection<Esame>> listTests = service
                .getTestsInterfaceAsync();


        Futures.addCallback(listTests, new FutureCallback<Collection<Tests>>() {

            public void onSuccess(Collection<Tests> tests) {
                response.resume(tests);
            }

            public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
                response.resume(thrown);
            }
        });
```

and if i call my api works well, i have this JSON:

```
{
 name=something
 result=6
 credit=12
}

{
 name=something
 result=6
 credit=12
}

{
 name=something
 result=6
 credit=12
}

{
 name=something
 result=6
 credit=12
}
```

now my question, if i want to add the status of response? for example:

```
{
 status=200
}
{
 name=something
 result=6
 credit=12
}
```

i must add Object status in a Tests class?..but in this case the result will be:

```
  {
     status=200
     name=something
     result=6
     credit=12
    }
 {
     status=200
     name=something
     result=6
     credit=12
    }
```

Comment: create a wrapper around your test class say StatusTest and have status Field along with Test class composed within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something

```
public class Result{
    private Integer status;
    private List<Tests> tests;

    // getters and setters 
}
```